# Allow access to CloudSQL from all GCE instances

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to grant blanket access to my CloudSQL instance from ALL (current and future) GCE instances?  I've tried adding the /16 internal network block address for my project's instances (copied from the "networks" tab under "Compute Engine": 10.240.0.0/16) but that won't save - it appears that I can only add single-machine (/32) IP addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the external IP of your machine, although they are both (GCE and Cloud SQL) in Google's datacenters, you cannot communicate between the two using internal IPs.

I do not think there is a native way to allow access from any instance in your project. The only way would be to make your own app to run on one of your instances and use the GCE api to periodically query running instances, get their external ip's, and then use the CloudSQL API to modify the security configuration on the CloudSQL instance.

You could improve this slightly creating a pool of static IP's that you assign to your GCE machines that are going to access your CloudSQL instance, that way the IP's would not change, the side affect is that you would be charged for IP's that you have reserved but do not have allocated to instances.

Apart from that you would have to put a rule to allow any IP access (e.g. 1.0.0.0/0), which would not be a good idea.

Comment: Ugh.  I was afraid that would be the case.  Its a real pain having to add/remove IP addresses from the whitelist every time I spin up or down GCE instances.  I hope Google offers some kind of solution for this soon...

Comment: I wanted to add a comment to this to avoid billing confusion. One of the issues that concerned me about only being able to add an external IP even if it was a GCE VM instance that would communicate with Cloud SQL, was being afraid of being charged for egress traffic between my Cloud SQL instance and my GCE VM. Google's network is smart enough to know that even though it's an external IP communicating between Cloud SQL and GCE VM instances, it won't charge you egress traffic because it knows it's its own network.

Comment: Right now what I do is I set the authorized network to 0.0.0.0/0, and put in a strong password for root and other user accounts and change them periodically. Not a good solution but not much of a choice.